# How to compare row from function which returns cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have function which returns cursors and returns 4 rows with `ID(number),name(varchar),value(number),GAME_NAME_ID(number), GNAME(varchar), RNUM(number).`

Now I have to compare 3rd row from this function with some other parameter.

this is function and the ouput

```
select aff_setings.v$list_game_parameters_for_aff(4355,15,0,20) from dual;

Cursor (GAME_PARAMETAR_ID, NAME, VALUE, GAME_NAME_ID, GNAME, RNUM)              
------------------------------------------------------------------------
5, MAX_WIN, 100, 15, Royal , 1                                        
6, MAX_GAMBLE, 100, 15, Royal , 2                                     
8, MAX_BET, 50, 15, Royal , 3                                         
11, MIN_BET, 10, 15, Royal, 4
```

How will I compare 3rd row, just one parameter for example VALUE(50) with some other parameter or just to single out specific row column?

Comment: is the results returned as separate rows and columns or combined column with multiple rows?

Comment: if the output returned is in a single row with all values combined as a single string, you may need to split the data by comma using regex and then you can separate and compare individually

Comment: it returned in 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a way out to do that in pure SQL without changing your function definition. 
If you had used `TABLE` functions instead of  returning a `CURSOR`, things would have been simpler.

Here's how you could do it in PL/SQL though.

```
DECLARE
     v_game_parametar_id   INTEGER;
     v_name      VARCHAR2(20);
-- define all local variables to hold the cursor data
     v_cur             SYS_REFCURSOR := aff_setings.v$list_game_parameters_for_aff(4355,15,0,20); 
--load the cursor into a local refcursor
BEGIN
     LOOP
          FETCH v_cur INTO
               v_game_parametar_id,
               v_name;
               -- other variables
          EXIT WHEN v_cur%notfound;
          IF v_value = 50
          THEN
            do_the_comparision;
          END IF;
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

if your result is something like this:

`'1,2,3,4,test,etc'` as row1
`'1,2,3,4,test,etc'` as row2

then you can use below query

**This is how you could split the data by commas using regex** and extract the 3rd value `'[^,]+', 1, 3)` if you want the 4th value, you may replace it with `'[^,]+', 1, 4)`

```
 select REGEXP_SUBSTR(aff_setings.v$list_game_parameters_for_aff(4355,15,0,20), '[^,]+', 1, 3)  from dual;
```

**this is how you can compare the result with other values:**

```
select 
case when 
(select REGEXP_SUBSTR(aff_setings.v$list_game_parameters_for_aff(4355,15,0,20), '[^,]+', 1, 3)  from dual)
=50 then 1 else 0 end
from dual;
```

**if your result is returned as a cursor in a single row, here is how you can extract the required values:**

in this example, the id and name are two columns which has 4rows. if you want to extract 3rd row 2nd column:

```
WITH test_data (raw_text)
 AS 
  (SELECT '{<ID=1,NAME=test4>,<ID=2,NAME=test3>,<ID=3,NAME=test5>,<ID=4,NAME=test1>,}' from dual
  )
SELECT  
regexp_substr(regexp_substr(regexp_substr(raw_text, '\{([^}]+)\}', 1,1,NULL,1), '\<([^>]+)\>', 1,3,NULL,1),'[^,]+', 1, 2)
FROM test_data
;
```

Comment: But what if when i get it all in 1 row, will just count till value i need and put it instead of 3 or 4 in your example ?

Comment: I have added the code to extract the required data from single line data.
share the exact output (single line as you said) so that I could help you by making further changes. Hope this helps